# Primes in arithmetic progression with the first term and the common difference of minimum values.

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

The primes that form the subject of this question are of the form
P = Pi + Δi (0, 1, 2, 3,   Pi-1). So far, there are known only 7 sets of this type. They have the following first terms and common differences: 
Pi = {3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19} and 
Δi = {2, 6,150, 1536160080, 9918821194590, 341976204789992332560, 2166703103992332274919550}
If one neglects the first two differences  2 and  6  as insignificant, and plots the function Ln Δi = f(Pi) one obtains a straight line. 
Since there aren't too many linear correlations linking directly the prime numbers to relevant quantities, it would be interesting to calculate the difference Δ23 pertaining to the prime Pi = 23, and see if the point corresponding to its logarithm is situated on the above line. 
Knowing that  Δ23  is on the order of 10^32, and that all differences   Δ(Pn) are multiple of the primorial  P(n-1)#, can someone approximate the feasibility of  computing Δ23 using: a) an ordinary computer, b) a very powerful one and c) a polymath type collaboration ?

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A088430](https://oeis.org/A088430) and references there.  I think if the next term was easy to find, someone would have done so already.

Comment: According to [Primes in Arithmetic Progression Records](http://primerecords.dk/aprecords.htm), in 2017 Wojciech Izykowski found that $\Delta_i = 134181089232118748020 \cdot 19\#$ works for $P_i = 23$, but it is not known to be the least.

Comment: @Robert The post is not about establishing a new record, but of using the apparent linear correlation between the logarithms of the common distances and the corresponding prime. This allows the computing to be restricted to a relatively small interval around the expected value. Since the progress of the computation does not depend on previous results, it suits well for a polymath type collaboration because it can be done by different groups working on different number intervals.